# Install fails but enhanced logging does not contain errors

Tags: vsto, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce Office Add-In that inconsistently fails to install in a PowerShell script. The script is being run from SCCM. When it fails, the only error in the install log is a -400 return value, which of course means almost nothing. There is other output both before and after that error, and nothing stands out.

I was able to replicate this once while ClickOnce logging was turned on, and the output is below (no timestamps because I had to transcribe this by hand).

Failed install:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
  Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (WinNT)
  Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
  System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
  clr.dll             : 4.7.3260.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
  dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
  dfshim.dll          : 10.0.15063.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
  Deployment url         : file://path/to/my.vsto

ERROR SUMMARY
  No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
  No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
  There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
  No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
  No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
  No transaction information is available.

DETAILED EXECUTION FLOW
  Activation through IPHM APIs is started.
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager(file://path/to/my.vsto,False) called.
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.GetManifestAsync() called.
  Internal state=GettingManifest
  Method Call : DeploymentManager.BindAsync() called.
  Binding started in a worker thread.
  Internal state=DownloadingDeploymentInformation
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.Dispose() called.
  Internal state=Done
```

Successful install:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
  Windows             : 6.2.9200.0 (WinNT)
  Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
  System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
  clr.dll             : 4.7.3260.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
  dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2046.0 built by: NET47REL1
  dfshim.dll          : 10.0.15063.0 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SOURCES
  Deployment url         : file://path/to/my.vsto
  Application url        : file://path/to/my/Application Files/my_1_0_0_123/my.dll.manifest

IDENTITIES
  Deployment Identity    : my.vsto, Version=1.0.0.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil
  Application Identity   : my.dll, Version=1.0.0.123, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

APPLICATION SUMMARY
  * Online only application

ERROR SUMMARY
  No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
  No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
  There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
  No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
  No errors were detected during this operation.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
  No transaction information is available.

DETAILED EXECUTION FLOW
  Activation through IPHM APIs is started.
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager(file://path/to/my.vsto,False) called.
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.GetManifestAsync() called.
  Internal state=GettingManifest
  Method Call : DeploymentManager.BindAsync() called.
  Binding started in a worker thread.
  Internal state=DownloadingDeploymentInformation
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.Dispose() called.
  expectedAppId=file://path/to/my.vsto#my.vsto, Version=1.0.0.123, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil/my.dll, Version=1.0.0.123, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
  Application is not found in store.
  Internal state=DownloadingApplicationInformation
  _cached=False
  _isUpdate=False
  Binding is successful.
  Creating GetManifestCompletedEventArgs.
  Application Identity=file://path/to/my.vsto, Version=1.0.0.123, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil/my.dll, Version=1.0.0.123, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<an alphnumeric value>, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32
  IsCached=False
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.DownloadApplicationAsync() called.
  Internal state=DownloadingApplcication
  Method Call : DeploymentManager.SynchronizeAsync() called.
  Download and install of the application started ina  worker thread.
  Application is not cached.
  Application is successfully committed to the store.
  Refreshing ActivationContext from store.
  Installation is successful.
  Internal state=Done
  Method Call : InPlaceHostingManager.Dispose() called.
  Internal state=Done
```

Note that there are no actual errors in the failed install.

When I do see this, it does not re-occur a second time. How do I troubleshoot this further?